# app client server, wrong accumulator number

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

i created a socket based client server application ... this is what it basically has to do ....
Define a socket-based client server application. The server must be able to respond to multiple clients simultaneously.
The server generates a single positive integer value N, to be used for each client that connects.
When connecting, the client randomly generates an integer M.
The client then sends positive integer values ​​to server M.
The transmission ended by sending the value -1.
Each time a client finishes transmitting, the server writes to the screen the number of values ​​greater than N received so far from all clients.
If necessary, manage synchronization issues.

This is what I managed to do .... I have a doubt though ..
When I run the client it tells me how many positive integers it sends, for example 40 .... The server will then tell me how many of these are greater than the number N generated by the client, for example 10 .... But if I run the client again , this will add the previous integers greater than N with the new number of integers greater than N giving me an incorrect result.
Now I wonder ... is this normal or did I do something wrong?

```
        package server;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.net.ServerSocket;
        import java.net.Socket;
        import java.util.logging.Level;
        import java.util.logging.Logger;


        public class Server {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(5555);
        int N;
        N = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        System.out.println("Server online, il numero N che adopera è : "+N);

        Accumulatore a = new Accumulatore();
        while(true){
        Socket client = s.accept();
        ThreadServer t = new ThreadServer(client,N,a);
        t.start();
        
       
        
        }
        
         
        
           // TODO code application logic here
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       // TODO code application logic here
     }
     }
   }      




        package server;
        import java.io.*;
        import java.net.Socket;
        import java.util.logging.Level;
        import java.util.logging.Logger;


        public class ThreadServer extends Thread{

       Socket s ;
       int M;
      Accumulatore acc;

      public ThreadServer(Socket s, int M, Accumulatore acc) {
      this.s = s;
      this.M = M;
      this.acc = acc;
        } 

        @Override
       public void run(){
        try {
        DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream()));
        int n;
        while((n = data.readInt())!=-1){
            if(n>M){
                acc.incrementa();
            }
        }
         System.out.println("Valori più grandi di "+M +" ricevuti : "+ acc.getn());
    
        
       data.close();    //////diocaneeeeeeeee
        s.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ThreadServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

}





      package client;

      import java.io.DataOutputStream;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.OutputStream;
      import java.net.Socket;
      import java.util.logging.Level;
      import java.util.logging.Logger;


      public class Client {


      public static void main(String[] args) {
    
      try(Socket client = new Socket("localhost",5555); 
          OutputStream i1 = client.getOutputStream();  
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(i1);) {
        
        int M;
        M= (int)(Math.random()*100);
        System.out.println("Invierò "+M+" interi positivi");

        // TODO code application logic here
        for(int i = 0; i<M; i++){
            int l;
            l = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            out.writeInt(l);
            out.flush();
        }
        out.writeInt(-1);
        out.flush();
        
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
     }

      }



        package server;


        public class Accumulatore {

        private int n = 0;    


       synchronized public void incrementa(){
      n++;        
     }
     public int getn(){
      return n;
   }

   }
```

Comment: Your description is inconsistent; first you write _The server generates a single positive integer value N_, then you write _the number N generated by the client_. Regarding the question _is this normal or did I do something wrong?_ - What's _normal_ depends on the norm, and what the program is supposed to do you have to know by yourself.

Comment: I don't understand where the inconsistency is, the server generates an integer N to use for each client that connects while the client generates M, that is, M integers that it will send to the server ...

Comment: Then why do you say _the number N generated by the client_? N can't be generated by the server and the client as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Armali wrote in the comment - it depends on the application requirement whether it is wrong or not. The application logic has one instance of the classs `Accumulatore`. This instance is created before any connection from client and sum up all comming connection. The server uses the same `Accumulatore` instance when a new connection is created.

If the numbers should be counted separately for each connection you need to create a separate `Accumulatore` instance when a new connection is received in the `main` method. Something like that:

```
...
N = (int)(Math.random()*100);
System.out.println("Server online, il numero N che adopera è : "+N);
while(true) {
    Socket client = s.accept();
    Accumulatore a = new Accumulatore();
    ThreadServer t = new ThreadServer(client,N,a);
    t.start();
...
```